# Storing different std::tuple types in an array, vector or?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdbind, stdtuple

Is there any way in the latest C++ version (17 or 20 I guess) to store different kinds of tuples in a std::array or std::vector or other built-in data type?  For example maybe something like ->

```
struct bunchOfTuples {
    std::tuple<float, float, int, int> firstTup = std::make_tuple(float, float, int, int);
    std::tuple<float, float, int> secondTup = std::make_tuple(float, float, int); };
    // bunch more tuples of differing types
};
```

Is there some way using templates to achieve something similar?  Or a class or struct implementation?  Or another way I haven't thought of I am kind of new to the latest C++ stuff?  I am working on an automatic method invocation project.  I have something that basically works but this would make it cleaner.

Comment: `std::variant` or some sort of type erasure would do the trick, but you can't store heterogeneous types in homogeneous containers.

Comment: Why not make a tuple of tuples? You can access individual members from a numeric index using `std::get`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays, vectors and in fact all standard containers are homogeneous. This means that all elements of the container have the same type. Different instances of the `std::tuple` template are different classes. As such, they cannot be stored in one array.

C++ does have heterogeneous wrappers: `std::variant` and `std::any`. Variant is an implementation of a tagged union. It can be used to store an object from a pre-defined list of types. `any` is a type safe wrapper for `void*`. it can store an object of any type. So, a container of variant or `any` might be useful to you.

They are only low level tools though, and for more featured heterogeneous processing, there are existing libraries such as Boost.Hana.